# Запятая перед тире не поглощается?

Tags: пунктуация

> ... царевич, сделав вид, что отходит к
> стеллажу**,** — выскочил за дверь.

... или здесь работает правило «Тире может ставиться вместо запятой (например, для выделения приложений, в сложном предложении и т. п.), но, если каждый из этих знаков ставится по своим условиям, они не поглощают друг друга».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно.

Запятая закрывает придаточное предложение, а тире является интонационным и обозначает паузу при резкой смене событий, неожиданном повороте действия.

Answer (score 1):

Тире здесь не может употребляться ВМЕСТО запятой, так как это отнесет "выскочил за дверь" к придаточному "что отходит к стеллажу", а не к "царевич", поэтому придаточное надо закрыть.

Но тире мне кажется неуместным. Паузы я здесь не вижу. Ср.: *Царевич сделал вид, что отходит к стеллажу, — и выскочил за дверь.*